# Is my ASUS F200M 64-bits Notebook PC compatible with Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: compatibility

Is my ASUS F200M 64-bits Notebook PC compatible with Ubuntu 15.04?

My PC is not in the certified PC list of www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog web side.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Lenovo with almost the same specs, and it work perfect with Ubuntu.  The only issue I had was the wireless connection, but that has a solution that works. I tried with both 14.04, and 15.04, and both work fine.

So go ahead, and go for it.  But if you want to be more sure, you can run Ubuntu live, and see if you have any issues.